# User Mode vs Userland

Tags: usermode, userland

Is **Userland** just another way to say **User Space** & **User-Mode**?

For example, would I be able to say:

There are various subsystems in **Userland**.

Instead of:

There are various subsystems in **User-Mode**.

..and would it be a valid way of saying that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They're similar, but I think there's a subtle semantic difference. User-mode is a *state of execution*; usually it involves having restricted access to processor features (i.e. Ring 3 on x86), using syscalls to get services from the kernel, and not having kernel memory mapped. At any time a thread is either running in user mode or kernel mode.

Userland is the *collection of software* that runs in user-mode — for instance, you could say that Android has a Linux kernel but a radically modified userland, or that Debian GNU/kFreeBSD has a FreeBSD kernel but a Linux-derived userland. It's a colloquialism for everything that's not the kernel, or sometimes everything that would be considered the "operating system" except the kernel.